# Can someone help me understand the following logic related to inheritance strategy in hibernate?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, inheritance

This text is taken from a book named **Spring persistence with hibernate** and author is describing the shortcomings of **one table for each concrete class** inheritance strategy in hibernate. In the given example, Student and Teacher are child classes of Person class and Person is associated with Address class. I'm not able to understand this particular argument which is given below:-

> *Imperfect support for polymorphic associations: The problem occurs when
>   a parent class is associated with another persistent class. In our example,
>   suppose Person is associated with an Address class, so both Student and
>   Teacher are associated with Address, as well. To map this class hierarchy
>   according to this approach, we need these four tables in our database
>   schema: PERSON, STUDENT, TEACHER, and ADDRESS. **If Address has a
>   many-to-one relationship with Person (more than one person may have
>   the same address), then the ADDRESS table should provide a foreign key
>   reference to all PERSON, STUDENT, and TEACHER tables, in order to establish
>   database-level relationship, but this is not possible.***

Why is it not possible for Address table to provide foreign key reference to PERSON, STUDENT, and TEACHER tables?

Comment: In database it is possible for address table to have foreign keys to four tables;

Comment: @JaySmith It **is possible** or **not possible**?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have three different database tables `PERSON`, `STUDENT` and `TEACHER` how would you define the foreign key constraint on the table `ADDRESS`?

```
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY fk_address_owner
ADDRESS.owner_id
REFERENCES (which table?) (id)
```

As you can see, you would have to point to three database tables. That's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` it is not possible to implement `Address` has many-to-one relation to `Person`. Hibernate doesn't create the association.

But It is possible to create unidirectional one-to-many between `Student` and `Address`. Here is  `Address` entity :

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String address;

    public Address() {
    }
```

`Person` entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Person() {
    }
```

`Student` entity subclasses `Person` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student extends Person {
    @OneToMany()
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Address> addresses;

    public Student() {
    }
```

Because of `@JoinColumn` annotation hibernate creates `student_id` column in `address` table and adds foreign key constraint. HIbernate logs:

```
Hibernate: 

    create table Address (
        id bigint not null,
        address varchar(255),
        student_id bigint,
        primary key (id)
    )

Hibernate: 

    create table persons (
        id bigint not null,
        name varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 

    create table students (
        id bigint not null,
        name varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 

    alter table Address 
        add constraint FKpe2jekm3pchvipc2cct5u5win 
        foreign key (student_id) 
        references students (id)
```

Bidirectional association between `Student` and `Address` can be implemented:

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String address;

    @ManyToOne
    private Student student;

    public Address() {
    }
```

And `Student` entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student extends Person {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="student")
    private List<Address> addresses;

    public Student() {
    }
```

Hibernate creates the same db tables as in unidirectional one-to-many above.

But with `InheritanceType.JOINED` it is possible to create bidirectional many-to-one between `Address` and `Person`,`Student`. Here is `Address` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String address;

     @ManyToOne
     private Person person;

    public Address() {
    }
```

`Person` entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
    private List<Address> addresses;

    public Person() {
    }
```

`Student` entity is :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student extends Person {

    private String email;

    public Student() {
    }
```

Hibernate creates tables:

```
Hibernate: 

    create table Address (
        id bigint not null,
        address varchar(255),
        person_id bigint,
        primary key (id)
    )

Hibernate: 

    create table persons (
        id bigint not null,
        name varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 

    create table students (
        email varchar(255),
        id bigint not null,
        primary key (id)
    )

Hibernate: 

    alter table Address 
        add constraint FKtaq05im3hxcvufy75xk044251 
        foreign key (person_id) 
        references persons (id)
Hibernate: 

    alter table students 
        add constraint FK9nqs0pkter5l6no6n9v93uyau 
        foreign key (id) 
        references persons (id)
```

`students` table references `persons` table via `FK9nqs0pkter5l6no6n9v93uyau` constraint. `address` table references `persons` table via `FKtaq05im3hxcvufy75xk044251`. This means that hibernate handles one-to-many between `Student` entity and `Address` entity in `addresses` collection of `Person` entity. Any entity that subclasses `Person` has one-to-many relation to `Address` entity.

With `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` it is possible to create bidirectional many-to-one between `Address` and `Student`. Here is `Address` entity:

```
    @Entity
    public class Address {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        private String address;

         @ManyToOne
         private Person person;

        public Address() {
        }
```

`Person` entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
    private List<Address> addresses;

    public Person() {
    }
```

`Student` entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student extends Person {

    private String studentEmail;

    public Student() {
    }
```

Hibernate creates single table for fields in `Student` and `Person` entities:

```
Hibernate: 

    create table Address (
        id bigint not null,
        address varchar(255),
        person_id bigint,
        primary key (id)
    )

Hibernate: 

    create table persons (
        DTYPE varchar(31) not null,
        id bigint not null,
        name varchar(255),
        studentEmail varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
Hibernate: 

    alter table Address 
        add constraint FKtaq05im3hxcvufy75xk044251 
        foreign key (person_id) 
        references persons (id)
```

`Student` entity has one-to-many relation to `Address` entity because of `FKtaq05im3hxcvufy75xk044251` constraint.